# Show a list of applications like alt-tab in Win7

Tags: c++, winapi, alt-tab

I am trying to print a list of running applications like alt-tab would give me. Here are what I have done so far:

1.In the beginning I tried EnumWindows, but I got hundreds of entries.

2.I found some similar questions and they led me to the blog of Raymond Chen.
     http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/08/5351207.aspx

However it still shows more than 100 windows(window_num1 being 158 and window_num2 being 329), while alt-tab would give me only 4. What did I do wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

HWND windowHandle;
int window_num1=0;
int window_num2=0;

BOOL IsAltTabWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
    if (hwnd == GetShellWindow())   //Desktop
        return false;
    // Start at the root owner
    HWND hwndWalk = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOTOWNER);

    // See if we are the last active visible popup
    HWND hwndTry;
    while ((hwndTry = GetLastActivePopup(hwndWalk)) != hwndTry) 
    {
        if (IsWindowVisible(hwndTry)) 
            break;
        hwndWalk = hwndTry;
    }
    return hwndWalk == hwnd;
}

BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR title[500];
    ZeroMemory(title, sizeof(title));

    //string strTitle;

    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, sizeof(title)/sizeof(title[0]));

    if (IsAltTabWindow(hWnd))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Value is %s\n"), title);
        window_num1++;
    }
    window_num2++;

    //strTitle += title; // Convert to std::string
    if(_tcsstr(title, _T("Excel")))
    {
        windowHandle = hWnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

void MyFunc(void) //(called by main)
{
    EnumWindows(MyEnumProc, 0);
}

int main() 
{
    MyFunc();
    cout<<endl<<window_num1<<endl<<window_num2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You failure is, that you should walk only visible windows... read the blog again.

> For each **visible window**, walk up its owner chain until you find
>   the root owner. Then walk back down the visible last active popup
>   chain until you find a visible window. If you're back to where you're
>   started, then put the window in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↹Tab</kbd> list.

Your code walks over every window!

Comment: Oh gosh how could I forgot that! Now I got 6 windows, 3 of them being alt-tab windows and the other 3 have no title. I guess what I need to do next is to enumerate those special cases and not showing them?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `IsWindowVisible`

```
BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR title[256] = {0,};
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && GetWindowTextLength(hWnd) > 0)
    {
       window_num1++;
       GetWindowText(hWnd, title, _countof(title));
       _tprintf(_T("Value is %d, %s\n"), window_num1, title);
    }
    return TRUE;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your code and I got one unwanted window, for which I think a walk-thru is still needed. GetWindowTextLength is really helpful.